# How to rename columns while reading multiple files using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, rename

I have two data frames (to excel files) with the below columns

**File 1- columns**

```
person_ID   Test_CODE   REGISTRATION_DATE   subject_CD   subject_DESCRIPTION    subject_TYPE
```

**File 2- columns**

```
person_ID   Test_CODE   REGISTRATION_DATE   subject_Code subject_DESCRIPTION    subject_Indicator
```

However, the columns `subject_CD`  and `subject_Code` mean the same. Similarly, `subject_TYPE` and `subject_Indicator` mean the same. So, I would like to rename them when I read the excel file

I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
dfs = []       
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    print(df.columns)
    df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(['person_ID','Test_CODE','REGISTRATION_DATE','subject_CD','subject_DESCRIPTION','subject_TYPE'])].rename(columns={'subject_TYPE':'subject_Indicator','subject_CD':'subject_Code'})
    dfs.append(df1)
```

Since, I would like to append/merge both the files, I expect the column names in my final data frame to be like as shown below

```
person_ID   Test_CODE   REGISTRATION_DATE   subject_Code subject_DESCRIPTION subject_Indicator
```

Can help me with this?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - updated the column names expected in final dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retain the columns of the first file which is read you can do something like this which stores the columns of the first iteration and assigns the column to the rest of the files:

```
dfs = []       
for e,f in enumerate(files):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    print(df.columns)
    if e == 0:
        col = df.columns
    df.columns=col
    dfs.append(df)


Index(['person_ID', 'Test_CODE', 'REGISTRATION_DATE', 'subject_CD',
       'subject_DESCRIPTION', 'subject_TYPE'],
      dtype='object')
Index(['person_ID', 'Test_CODE', 'REGISTRATION_DATE', 'subject_Code',
       'subject_DESCRIPTION', 'subject_Indicator'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

```
[df.columns for df in dfs] #pd.concat(dfs)

[Index(['person_ID', 'Test_CODE', 'REGISTRATION_DATE', 'subject_CD',
        'subject_DESCRIPTION', 'subject_TYPE'],
       dtype='object'),
 Index(['person_ID', 'Test_CODE', 'REGISTRATION_DATE', 'subject_CD',
        'subject_DESCRIPTION', 'subject_TYPE'],
       dtype='object')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Rename 2 columns from particular df:

```
 df.rename({"subject_CD": "subject_Code", "subject_TYPE": "subject_Indicator"}, axis='columns', inplace =True)
```

Also You can connect df1 and df2 - on the same columns:

[image]

```
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. But when I read the 2nd file (in loop), it will not have the column `subject_CD` right? Wouldn't that throw error?

Comment: @piotr - You mean to suggest that `df.rename` will have no effect if a specific column is not there in the dataframe. It will not throw any error but just switch to next line for execution. AM I right>

Comment: for concat dataframes - they should have identical columns - 
if the df does not contain a column - it can be added with the value of NAN - or removed from the other

Comment: @TheGreat - based on documentation - You can pass: errors='ignore' - argument
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: @TheGreat why not try it out yourself? I've just tried it on a random DataFrame and no errors, no warnings were raised.