# How to dynamically add missing columns while reading batch csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have 12 csv files to be read in a single output dataframe. The columns that I want in the final output dataframe are spread across multiple files. For example, as shown below

**Column list from files 1-8**

```
person_ID, Test_CODE, REGISTRATION_DATE, subject_CD, subject_DESCRIPTION, subject_TYPE
```

**Column list from File 9**

```
person_ID, Test_CODE, REGISTRATION_DATE, subject_Code, subject_DESCRIPTION, subject_Indicator
```

**Column list from File 10-12**

```
person_ID, Test_CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE, subject_Code, subject_DESCRIPTION, subject_Indicator
```

Based on my domain understanding, I know that columns `START_DATE` and `REGISTRATION_DATE` mean the same.

Similarly, `subject_CD` and `subject_Code` mean the same.

So, I tried the below with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841114/how-to-rename-columns-while-reading-multiple-files-using-pandas) for renaming the columns.

```
dfs = []       
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    print(df.columns)
    df1 = df[df.columns.intersection(['person_ID','Test_CODE','REGISTRATION_DATE','subject_CD','subject_DESCRIPTION'])].rename(columns={'subject_CD':'subject_Code','REGISTRATION_DATE':'START_DATE'})
    dfs.append(df1)
```

However, I am not sure `how can I add a column on the fly` because `files 1-9` are missing `END_DATE`. While I would like to just have a column `END_DATE` with no data in it. Only if I have the column `END_DATE`, I will be able to append all my input data frames and obtain a final output dataframe.

Or is it possible to append a dataframe based on common columns and just add a `END_DATE` column in final output dataframe (after the append)?

I expect my final dataframe to have the columns as shown below

**Column list from final output dataframe**

```
person_ID, Test_CODE, START_DATE, END_DATE, subject_Code, subject_DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first use `rename` and then [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for return only columns passed in list, if col in list not exist in DataFrame is appended filled by missing values:

```
d = {'subject_CD':'subject_Code','REGISTRATION_DATE':'START_DATE'}
cols = ['person_ID','Test_CODE','START_DATE','END_DATE',
        'subject_Code','subject_DESCRIPTION']

dfs = []       
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    print(df.columns)
    df1 = df.rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=cols)
    dfs.append(df1)
```

List comprehension alternative:

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f, sep=",",low_memory=False).rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=cols) 
       for f in files]
```

Test data:

```
print (df1)
  person_ID Test_CODE REGISTRATION_DATE subject_CD subject_DESCRIPTION  \
0       id1        aa        2015-01-01       sub1                desc   

  subject_TYPE  
0        type1 

print (df2)
  person_ID Test_CODE REGISTRATION_DATE subject_Code subject_DESCRIPTION  \
0       id2        bb        2017-01-01         sub1               desc2   

  subject_Indica  
0          type2 

print (df3)
  person_ID Test_CODE  START_DATE    END_DATE subject_Code  \
0       id3        cc  2017-01-01  2017-08-06         sub3   

  subject_DESCRIPTION subject_Indicator  
0               desc3             type3
```

---

```
d = {'subject_CD':'subject_Code','REGISTRATION_DATE':'START_DATE'}
cols = ['person_ID','Test_CODE','START_DATE','END_DATE',
        'subject_Code','subject_DESCRIPTION']


dfs = []       
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    # df = pd.read_excel(f, sep=",",low_memory=False)
    #print(df.columns)
    df1 = df.rename(columns=d).reindex(columns=cols)
    dfs.append(df1)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
  person_ID Test_CODE  START_DATE    END_DATE subject_Code subject_DESCRIPTION
0       id1        aa  2015-01-01         NaN         sub1                desc
1       id2        bb  2017-01-01         NaN         sub1               desc2
2       id3        cc  2017-01-01  2017-08-06         sub3               desc3
```

Comment: If the columns listed in `cols` list is not present in the data, I believe it will return `NA` for that column. Sorry, I couldn't try as I am away from my desk

Comment: @TheGreat - Sure, it return `NaN`s, this ways workign `reindex`

Comment: @TheGreat - aded test data to solution for see it.